# AngularFire Watch and Retrieve Item Key

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to watch my firebase array for changes and call a function when the changes take effect.

I have achieved this however, I am not able to get the `key` that firebase uses to store the data so I can pass it onto my function I am calling.

The key being `-JrFJO3-vJ8DBHovapub` or the top most child of a node like `estimates`

```
estimates
{
   -JrFJO3-vJ8DBHovapub
  {
     ....
  }
  ....
}
```

My current code looks like such:

```
$scope.estimates.$watch(function(data) {
   if(data.event == "value") {
      angular.forEach($scope.estimates, function(estimate) {
         es.findTotal();
      });
   }
});
```

Is what I have right now. How do I obtain the key when a value event is called?

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you create `$scope.estimates`. But if it's a `$firebaseArray`, you probably want to extend it in the way documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

Comment: All I want to do is to get the edited key to be able to call a function that requires the key to work. If that would make it work. then put it in an answer. The point of this website.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the new value `data`, instead of `$scope.stimates`?

```
$scope.estimates.$watch(function(data) {
    if(data.event == "value") {
        angular.forEach(data, function(estimate, KEY) {
            console.log(KEY); //estimate key
            es.findTotal();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Because that `console.log(KEY)` displays the word `event`

Comment: Not `-JrFJO3-vJ8DBHovapub` as placed as an example in my question.